# I want to know the output of a SQL UPDATE CASE QUERY

Tags: sql

[Table on which query is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8u28.png)   I am operating the following query on this table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Aq71.png)

```
**What will be the output of this query on the above table:** 



 UPDATE dsp
   SET dsp.HasVersionNumber = CASE 
                                WHEN dsp.ShouldHaveVersionNumber - 1 <= 6 THEN dsp.ShouldHaveVersionNumber 
                                ELSE dsp.ShouldHaveVersionNumber - 1
                              END
  FROM dbo.DeviceProfileStatus dsp    
 WHERE dsp.ProfileId = 10000003
   AND dsp.HasVersionNumber <= 6
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That UPDATE FROM syntax is product specific.)

Comment: Most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to update the column `dsp.ShouldHaveVersionNumber` only if its value is **not** `dsp.ShouldHaveVersionNumber - 1 <= 6`, so I think that your code should be written like this:

```
UPDATE dsp
SET dsp.HasVersionNumber = dsp.ShouldHaveVersionNumber - 1 
FROM dbo.DeviceProfileStatus dsp    
WHERE dsp.ProfileId = 10000003 AND dsp.HasVersionNumber > 7
```

For the sample data you posted **no row will be updated**, because the only row with `dsp.ProfileId = 10000003` does not have `dsp.HasVersionNumber <= 6`, it is `null`.